# C2DM Behavior over Wifi and 3G

Tags: android-c2dm

I'm developing an app which relies on C2DM to be notified of some new data to be fetched from a REST service. I have successfully implemented the C2DM android feature, but the behavior over Wifi is different from the connection over 3G. The messages are received instantly over 3G, but I have to manually turn Wifi off and on to have a "grace period" of ~1 min in which I receive them instantly.

My question is: Is there any way I can programmatically restart the connection, or trigger the notification fetch?

EDIT:
I've implemented an AsyncTask that periodically "reassociates" the connection to the access point (using WifiManager.reassociate()) every minute and a half. Not so sure about the correctness of this solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issues. It seems that under some circumstances C2DM messages are not delivered over wifi connections, when they are over 3G. On a related note I've also seen Android devices "drop" the push connection, so messages are not delivered (in my case the solution can be to put the device in airplane mode and then turn the network back on).

This reinforces the fact that all applications that use C2DM should be built so that even if push messaging fails, the app still works (even if messages/updates are slower because there's occasional polling to the server)

I wouldn't personally want to mess with the wifi connection as that's something that may cause problems for the user.